# Remove preload element in CSS

Tags: css, preload, preloadjs

I designed a template-based web page: [Website](http://www.citricosamatlan.com.mx)

Whenever a page is loading there's a horrible brown circle (with transparency) that appears in the front and it shouldn't.

The only thing my template service provider allows me in the code is to include CSS. So do you suggest any simple code that could either take this element off, make it 100% transparent or change its color to background?

I assume it must be related to something like:

```
preloader {
  display: none;
}
```

The simplest things sometimes are not as easy as they seem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, it just targets the "horrible brown circle" and hides it before it can show

```
.loading-central {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a loading indicator, So I just make it to work instead of hiding it.

```
.loading-central {
  animation: pulse 1.7s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%, 100% {
    background-color: #FFF;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #d8ae6c;
    transform: scale(.7);
  }
}
```